#  Match if several identical characters in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to match if a string contains more than 1 identical character, for example :
Using PHP preg_match or similar function.

the character would be "-"

Something-or other : no match
Test-tes-t : match

Basically what I want to do is disallow the use of more than 1 "-" in a user input.

Answer (score 6):

Isn't just `substr_count($text, '-') > 1` enough?

Comment: I second this - there are many cases where regex is not, in fact, the answer.